# sharepoint 2010 folder all ribbon controls disabled

Tags: document-library, ribbon, folder, library

I have a folder into a Doc Library the has a problem. All folder pages doesn't have ribbon controls enabled. It doesn't happen only in the first page.

I have Full Control permission in the entire Farm.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check the permissions.  Even though you have 'full control on the entire farm' that could mean that you have full control defined at the highest level, but any subsite or library could break that permissions inheritance.

Are you a site collection administrator?  If so, then you definitely have a problem.

Comment: yes, i'm site coll admin. Now I chaged the view with "All items" in the same page, and I have the controls enabled again. Could this be related with the fact that, my has 7300 items? :/

Comment: Yes, good find!  You have most likely exceed the 'list threshold' for your site.  this is defined in central admin, and the default is 5000.